# Missing Get_favicon function in new Simplepie Release

Tags: simplepie

In the new release the get_favicon method was removed as shown in the [Changes in this Release](http://simplepie.org/wiki/misc/release_notes/simplepie_1.3) section of documentation.

When I try `$item->get_favicon()` I only get `Call to undefined method SimplePie_Item::get_favicon()`

How am I able to get the favicons from the RSS Feeds?

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I've seeing the same error... Even searched through the code and there is no reference to anything related to favicon

Comment: The developer has added that this is by design and will not be added back

Answer (score 1):

get_favicon is a method for the feed itself, not its items. I believe $item->, means you are looping through the feed items.

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($xmlurl);
$feed->set_output_encoding('UTF-8');
$feed->set_cache_durat
$feed->enable_order_by_date(false);ion(30);
$feed->get_favicon();
```

I think where  you are in your code is inside the foreach going through each item. I dont think you can call the get_favicon method on the items.
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):